# How to get the expression for this partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I was asked to calculate what the sum of the following series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{4n^2-1}$$ I split up the fraction into $$\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}$$ From here I wasn't sure what to do so I checked the answers which said that from this we can see that the partial sum up to $m$ is given by $$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{2}{4n^2-1}=1-\frac{1}{2m+1}\tag{1}$$ and that this converges to $1$ as $m\to\infty$. I don't understand how $\frac{1}{2m+1}\to0$ and how they came to the equation in $(1)$.

**EDIT:** The question on why $\frac{1}{2m+1}\to0$ was in reference to why the series $\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{2}{4n^2-1}$ doesn't tend to $0$ because both sequences $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ and $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ tend to zero. I accidently overlooked the difference.

Comment: Write out the first few terms in $$\sum\left({1\over2n-1}-{1\over2n+1}\right)$$ and see what you get. As for how $1/(2m+1)\to0$, if you don't understand that, then what do you understand about limits?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: If you don't understand how $\frac{1}{2m+1} \to 0$ when $m \to \infty$ I suggest you go back to the **very basics** of Calculus before trying to evaluate series likes the one in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that\begin{align}\require{cancel}\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)&=1-\cancel{\frac13}+\cancel{\frac13}-\cdots-\cancel{\frac1{2m-1}}+\cancel{\frac1{2m-1}}-\frac1{2m+1}\\&=1-\frac1{2m+1}.\end{align}

Comment: How couldn't I understand that there of numbers have to be got cancelled from some point of series. Nice! $\to +1$